# How to create a python package that requires another module of regular expressions 're'

Tags: python, module, package

I am creating a python package. That does some preprocessing on input text using regular expressions 're' module and returns the preprocessed text. My question is how can I import 're' inside the python package that I am creating. I am new to this and I am writing a python package for the first time.

My setup.py file contents are as follows :

```
from setuptools import setup 
import re

setup(name ="speech_text",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "preprocess text",
    long_description = "preprocess text", 
    packages = ['speech_text'],
    install_requires = ['re'])
```

'speech_text' is the name of my package that I am creating. I tried this way, but it is throwing error as follows :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement re
> (from speech-text==0.1) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for re (from speech-text==0.1)

speech_text.py is the file where all the preprocessing is done. I have imported 're' module there as well. However, I am not able to get rid of these two errors. So, my question is how can I import 're' module in my package code and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re` is a part of the standard library of Python, you should not have it in your `install_requires` parameter at all, it will always be present.